# Restore Windows boot from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, boot, macbook, hybrid-mbr

I have a Macbook with triple boot based on rEFIt and custom-configured hybrid MBR. Recently I needed to resize partitions a couple of times (due to reasons which are not important to this question). Since I was resizing system partition which Windows boots from, I have decided to do so from Ubuntu using gparted. What I have noticed is that gparted breaks my custom hybrid MBR and defaults to first 3 partitions one the drive. Therefore I re-configure it again using gdisk. Next problem is that after reboot Windows won't boot and request me to insert a CD to correct startup problems, which I have done previously and it worked great automagically - I just had to confirm that I want recovery toolkit to fix my startup problems.

However today (on Saturday) I have realized that my Windows install CD is in the office only when I couldn't boot into Windows anymore. I don't feel like going to the office just to fetch the CD and I also don't want to wait until Monday. Is it possible to recover Windows boot from Ubuntu without an install CD? If not, is it possible to create Windows 7 Recovery USB drive from under Ubuntu? Note that I am talking about recovery, not install as my USB is just 1 GB and won't be able to accommodate entire install.

P.S. I do realize that the question may not get answered before Monday, but even if you have an answer later - please write it as it may help someone else than me (or even me, but in future). I will pick an answer that solves described problem in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not for usb, but for a blank CD. You can get/make a recovery disk that can do exactly what the repair/fix option does on the windows 7 install DVD, but is unable to install the OS. For more see [here](http://cybernetnews.com/windows-7-recovery-disc/).

[32-bit ISO](http://bit.ly/iqmBnI)

[64-bit ISO](http://bit.ly/m7kfdG)

Comment: Thanks. Now all I need it to be able to "burn" it into bootable USB that I can use to start up on the Mac.

Comment: I think you can just burn the image to the USB (make sure its FAT32 or NTFS), via a process similar to steps 21 and onwards from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2432-usb-windows-7-installation-key-drive-create.html).